# Помогите разобраться с позицией курсора на элементе

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет, не могу разобраться как вычислить позицию курсора на определённом блоке, НЕ относительно всей страницы, а именно относительно этого блока. Те к примеру имеем блок с шириной 100px и высотой 50px, нужно определить pageX (от 0 до 100) и pageY (от 0 до 50) именно для этого блока. У меня какие то космические значения получаются + ещё как бы учитывать масштаб страницы...

```
$('.item').mousemove(function(e){
    var pos = $(this).position();   // position
    var tw = $(this).outerWidth();  // width
    var th = $(this).outerHeight(); // height

    var posx = (e.pageX - pos.left - tw); //why it no wrk?
    var posy = (e.pageY - pos.top - th);
});
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/3w3Zf/

Прошу, хоть намекните, в чём ошибка, может не тот метод jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось, всем спасибо!

```
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
```